# Build APK for the project which is using Gradle V2.10 in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

(After updating version) In Android studio 3, I can not build APK for my project which is using Gradle V2.10.

I can build and can run it on device, but when I build APK, I got this error,

> Cause: The version of Gradle you are using(2.10) does not support the
>   forTask() method on BuildActionExecuter. Support for this is available
>   in Gradle 3.5 and all later versions.

I tried updating the Gradle version to 3.5 but, it seems a lot of work, I had to  fix many dependencies and even I couldn't make it work with Gradle 3.5.

So I gave up upgrading Gradle version and I just want to know **is it able that I can build APK without updating Gradle?**

Comment: Gradle 2.10 is ancient, the current version is 4.5.1. What did you have to fix when doing the upgrade? Sure it was due to gradle?

Comment: Btw, are you talking about gradle (the build system) or the android gradle plugin?

Comment: After updating Gradle, I had to fix plugin too , the android-apk plugin is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same problem in my current project since i updated, My suggestion is try building using **Generate Signed build** .It saved my work

Answer (score 0):

```
I've Fixed it by changing Gradle distributionUrl in "gradle-wrapper.properties".

Here is what I have configured:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I'm looking for the way without updating Gradle version